# Google Play Store: "Designed for phones" - How to get rid of?

Tags: android, optimization, tablet

I am facing a problem with Google Play Store lately. So far, I was able to publish apps for phones and tablets without any problems. Lately in my newer apps I get the message "Designed for phones" and app is rank low in tablets. Probably Google has made the rules for tablets more strict, but I don't know how to make my app compatible with the new rules.

What I have done so far:

1. I have made large, and xlarge folders with the appropriate layout files.
2. I have upload hi-res screenshots for 7' and 10' tablets.
3. I target SDK v. 19.
4. I get no suggestions in Developer Console, it seems that there are no problems with the .apk

and still getting the "Designed for phones" tag. Am I missing something? The above steps worked fine so far with all my apps.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26719442/844882

Answer (score 3):

Some other things to try, as stated in the [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html)

- targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion in the  element must be greater than 10 (you have this though).
- You must have assets for tablets. This means providing icons (and other image assets)for at least one of these: hdpi, xhdpi, or xxhdpi.
- If declared in your Manifest,

  > < supports-screens> 'must not specify android:largeScreens="false" or android:xlargeScreens="false".'
- Declare Hardware Features Correctly:
  Not all tablets support certain hardware features such as a camera. Find any such features in the  in your manifest and replace with

  > < uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

  Your app should work seamlessly even if the user does not have a camera on her tablet.

Comment: Thanks! The solution in my case was to add assets to xxhdpi folder. It might be a requirement now.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and in my case, when I went into the "Optmization Tips" tab, it says I need to upload tablet screenshots:

> Upload at least one screenshot for 10-inch tablets to the Store Listing. Learn more

I already added 7-inch tablet screenshots.  Uploading 10-inch tablet screenshots of my app worked for me.